# Handling error on RxAndroid ForEach operator

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

*This is based on RxJava & RxAndroid 1.x*

I'm a sort of newbie to Rx things and I wanted to use the `forEach` operator but I'm not able to handle errors happening inside the `Action1`.

Here's my code:

```
Observable.from(listeningDocumentIds)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
        .forEach(id -> {
            detachDocumentChangeListener(listener, document);
        });
```

Some exceptions might be thrown by the `detachDocumentChangeListener` function but it seems that the `doOnError` is not doing its job.

One of the exception that can be thrown is a `NullPointerException` which is clearly a `RuntimeException` so I do not see why it is not catched by my `doOnError`.

While I'm here, is the `forEach`will correctly run on an `io` `thread` with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doOnError` can peek into errors coming from above it, not below. It is not an error handler as the error will continue downstream to the end consumer. Error handling is done via `onErrorResumeNext` for example. Otherwise, you should use the two argument `subscribe` instead of `forEach`:

```
Observable.from(listeningDocumentIds)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(id -> {
        detachDocumentChangeListener(listener, document);
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```